# How to prevent XSS attack on selected window.location in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code where i am user a method SwitchUser_Click.
I need to prevent or somehow encode the return value from the switchUser_Click as it includes the UserId of a user vulnerable to XSS attack or hacking.

```
function SwitchUser_Click(containerElement, OnSuccess) {
            var selecteduserId = $("select", containerElement).val();
            var makeDefault = $(":checkbox", containerElement).is(":checked");
            window.location = "Default.aspx?uId=" + selecteduserId + "&userActive=" + (makeDefault ? "1" : "0");
            OnSuccess();
        }
```

The belows code is called from aspx page by using Client.RegisterScript and passing the parameters.

```
function OpenSwitchUser(UserId,modCode,defUrl) {
            defaultUrl = defUrl;
            var options =
            {
                controlUrl: "~/Controls/SwitchUserDialog.ascx",
                params: { uid:UserId, mod: modCode},
                top: 70,
                width: 600,
                height: 2500,
                OKCallback: SwitchUser_Click,
                InitCallback: SwitchUserDialog_Init,
                cancelCallback: SwitchUser_Close
            };
            $.showControlDialog(options);
        }
```

My aspx.cs page here is the problem i need to find a better approach to this part

```
var parameterUserId = Request.QueryString["uId"]; //problem need a better appoach
```

I want to know how to encode my userId in the SwitchUser_Click method and decode it when its called. Or maybe there is some other way to do this .
Thank you

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense.  The user ID should be URL-encoded for sure, but what specifically are you trying to protect against?

Comment: I'm guessing you are talking about encrypting not encoding. Instead of doing it that way, if you are looking for a more secure way to accomplish click to switch users, you can have a database table that stores the user ID, a unique hash and a datetime variable. Pass the hash in the URL and use that against the database to find the user id. Then write a script that deletes data from that table after 30 mins. This will allow the hash strings to only have meaning for 30 mins.